# Change Woocommerce "quantity" text in products page for defined product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a product category that I would like to display a different "quantity" text next to the quantity selector.

example: I have a product category called "stone" which has stone countertops which customers enter their square footage. Instead of it saying quantity it would say "enter square footage". This would only apply to the product category "stone" because there are other products in different categories I don't want this on.

Comment: Have you tried solving this with code? Or done any research into plugins which could help? Please add more context to your problem, list things you've tried. I don't think this is configurable via WooCommerce alone, without either custom-coding or a plugin

Comment: I know I will need custom code in functions.php to achieve this function. I know it should be a really short string

Comment: It might not be. I'd suggest working on the problem yourself. And showing the other users on here what you have done to attempt to solve this problem before requesting assistance. (With respect: This isn't a free coding service.)

Answer (score 0):

```html
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');

function translate_reply($translated) {

if ( !has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
   $translated = str_ireplace('Quantity', 'Quantity', $translated);
    return $translated;
    
 }else{
   $translated = str_ireplace('Quantity', 'Enter Square Feet', $translated);
    return $translated;
 }
}
```